# Using a json file to store configurations for a dojo application

Tags: dojo, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a fontend web app using dojo that does a lot of calls to rest endpoints using xhr. I would like to have a place to store configurations for things like endpoint locations and html tag references. I thought I would use an xhr call to a json file to do this, but I am having trouble getting my functions to trigger in the right order/at all. Below is my main js file which has an init() function that I am passing as the callback to my conf initializer ("ebs/conf") module, also below. I have used the Chrome debugger to set breakpoints within my conf.get() method, and it looks as though it never gets called.

Can someone give me some advice please?

Main JS File:

```javascript
// module requirements
require([ "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "ebs/prices", "ebs/cart", "ebs/conf",
    "dojo/ready" ], function(dom, on, prices, cart, conf, ready) {

ready(function() {

    conf.get("/js/config.json", init());

    function init(config) {

        on(dom.byId("height"), "keyup", function(event) {
            prices.calculate(config);
        });
        on(dom.byId("width"), "keyup", function(event) {
            prices.calculate(config);
        });
        on(dom.byId("qty"), "keyup", function(event) {
            prices.calculate(config);
        });
        on(dom.byId("grills"), "change", function(event) {
            prices.calculate(config);
        });

        cart.putSampleCart();
        cart.load(config);

    }

});

});
```

And here is my 'conf' module ("ebs/conf"):

```javascript
define(["dojo/json", "dojo/request/xhr"], function(json, xhr) {
return {
    get : function(file, callback) {
        // Create config object from json config file
        var config = null;
        xhr(file, {
            handleAs : "json"
        }).then(function(config) {
            callback(config);
        }, function(error) {
            console.error(error);
            return error;
        });
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not passing the function as the callback.  You are executing it and passing the result as the second argument.

```
conf.get("/js/config.json", init());
```

should be

```
conf.get("/js/config.json", init);
```